# Select a checkbox based on a column value using XPath

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to automate the testing. I'm facing an issue with selecting the checkbox of a table row. So I'm using XPath to do this. I have to select the row based on the file name. Below is the HTML

**HTML**

```html
<form id="Runs3" action="" method="post">
 <table id="data_Runs1" class="project-data project-show-borders project-has-col-totals">
  <tbody>
   <tr class="project-alternate-row">
    <td id="ext-gen3" class="project-selectors" nowrap="">
     <input type="checkbox" onclick="Region.selectRow(this);" value="234" name=".select" title="Select/unselect row"/>
     <span style="display: inline-block; width: 16px; height: 10px;"/>
    </td>
    <td id="ext-gen11" align="left">
     <a href="/key/module/essays/direct.view?runId=234">Study1_AS_06-20-16_1.xml</a>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
```

This is the **XPATH** that I tried

```
//form[@id='Runs3']//a[text()='Study1_AS_06-20-16_1.xml']/preceding-sibling:://input[@name='.select']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is not a sibling to the desired `input`. Use [`preceding` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding) instead:

```
//a[. = 'Study1_AS_06-20-16_1.xml']/preceding::input
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `xPath` seems to be wrong try with below `xPath` :-

```
//a[text()='Study1_AS_06-20-16_1.xml']/preceding::input[@name='.select']
```

**Note** :- for more clarification about `xPath` need to follow [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp)

Hope it will help you..:)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this xpath:-
//form[@id='Runs3']//a[text()='Study1_AS_06-20-16_1.xml']/../preceding-sibling::td/input

It navigates to the parent column of the a tag and goes to the preceding column of the table containing the input...